# Data over Ethernet raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am using raspberry pi 4 model B, and I am trying to communicate with my pc using Ethernet. I wrote a python code that create a socket with the following:

```
import socket
   
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005
   
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
  data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
```

This code worked over the wifi, so I googled it and I found that we should use `“socket.AF_PACKET”` instead. Does someone have any idea?
Also I noticed that there is 2 ip when I write `ifconfig`, one is under lo and the other is under wlan0.

Answer (score 1):

lo, 127.0.0.1 is loopback and is only applicable to the system it is seen on. Virtually all systems will have one. You should use the IP address from wlan0.